# getting error to deploy era file in jboss

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x

i am want to deploy the ear file that contains the 4 project 3 war and one .jar the jar project is common for war projects in this the jar project is using the spring and hibernate. and the war project is using the struts when deploy on the jboss 7 getting these error

```
15:11:51,929 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."EyewatchEar.ear#EW": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."EyewatchEar.ear#EW": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: EW] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to parse order-by fragment
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.OrderByFragmentTranslator.render(OrderByFragmentTranslator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.sql.Template.renderOrderByStringTemplate(Template.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.<init>(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.<init>(OneToManyPersister.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:226)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: antlr.CommonToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token
    at antlr.CharScanner.makeToken(CharScanner.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByLexer.mIDENT(GeneratedOrderByLexer.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByLexer.nextToken(GeneratedOrderByLexer.java:138)
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.fill(TokenBuffer.java:69)
    at antlr.TokenBuffer.LA(TokenBuffer.java:80)
    at antlr.LLkParser.LA(LLkParser.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.expression(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.sortKey(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.sortSpecification(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.orderByFragment(GeneratedOrderByFragmentParser.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.OrderByFragmentTranslator.render(OrderByFragmentTranslator.java:60)
    ... 22 more
```

i am using JTA but not able to find what is going wrong, so if some one have the solution please help.

thanks in Adv.

Comment: Are you including Hibernate and/or antlr in your deployment?

Answer (score 3):

You probably found a solution but for future reference, here's a working solution using Maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-version}</version>

    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using JBoss AS7 and Hibernate. This error started appearing for me after I annotated one of my entity class fields with @OrderBy

The solution is to remove antlr and/or hibernate, as James suggested in his comment and let JBoss find those dependencies (they are included by with JBoss).

If you are using Maven and have a compile-time dependency on either antlr or hibernate, you should add `<scope>provided</scope>` in either of the dependencies to compile with but not include in your jar file.